# I cannot see reports from an older version of Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am having a huge problem here. I have tried to run my project, when I have done it I have got this message:

```
#ExternalChecksum("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\xxx\Report.rpt","{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}","279EAF2B70DD7A17F09A2C9C84D5ADF6")
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.1008
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have installed Crystal Reports version 13 in Visual Studio 2010 previously. When I have got this message, I have checked the version of .NET on my project, I have deleted the temporary files of ASP.NET, I have checked in the web.config all the references to Crystal Reports. All those are fine. I do not what to do, I am paralyzed. Could you please help me? I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Should your path to the report be as follows?

```
C:\Users\xxx\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\xxx\Report.rpt
```

Notice the "My Documents" change.  At least in Win7, that is the correct path to Project files (which is where I assume your rpt file is).

In other words, check that the path to your report is correct.